# MySQL partitions based on last two digits of a column

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

If i have a database of 100 million of records and would like to do search with less time as possible!

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`number` BIGINT(12) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`address` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `my_table_u` (`id` ASC, `number` ASC) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and it has data like this

```
(1, 981776166221,'name1','address1')
(2, 499383722122,'name2','address2')
(3, 983765018762,'name3','address3')
(4, 986544567897,'name4','address4')
(5, 990876544335,'name5','address5')
```

And i will **only** search by `number` and `number` filed is arbitrary numbers consist of 12 digits `XXXXXXXXXXXX`.

I  was thinking about doing `MYSQL partitioning` by doing 100 partitions, each carry records that has `number` filed ends with exact two digits as follow :-

```
p1 (ends with 01), 
p2 (ends with 02), 
p3 (ends with 03),
..,
p45 (ends with 45),
..,
p99 (ends with 99)
```

so that if i'm going to search for `number = 765372819827` it might be clear it will search inside partition `27` since last two digits are `27`.

**Does** it really makes searching more fast ?

**How** can i set partitions by that way (based on only last two digits of `number` filed)?

Comment: You cannot store 12 digit numbers in an int column. You cannot store `090876544335` with leading 0. So, is it really an it column? Are those credit card numbers?

Comment: Sorry, that was just example to show up the case but i've update it to `bigint`

Comment: Before you try partitioning or something, did you try creating an index `create index ix1 on t (number)`?

Comment: @SalmanA that is right, And i've updated the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The beginnings of an Answer.)

`PARTITIONing` is possible, but it is not likely to speed up your queries.  Since converting the table is a big chore, let's discuss other ways to improve the performance.  Please provide some examples of "search" queries.  From there, I may be able to advise on better indexes.  If not, I will advise on how to best use Partitioning.

If `number = 765372819827` is the only "search", then simply `INDEX(number)` solves your problem by changing the query from "check 100M rows" to "check 1 row".

And do Drop `my_table_u`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating an index on `number` (make it unique index if it is) and that should be it.

The existing unique index on `(id, number)` does not make sense since `id` itself is a unique key. Also, it cannot be used by MySQL for `WHERE number = ...` since `number` is stored on leaf nodes.